# Spring-WebFlux Flux fails with Context

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to use `Context` in my Flux pipe to bypass filtering.

Here's what I have:

```
public Flux<Bar> realtime(Flux<OHLCIntf> ohlcIntfFlux) {
        return Flux.zip(
                ohlcIntfFlux,
                ohlcIntfFlux.skip(1),
                Mono.subscriberContext().map(c -> c.getOrDefault("isRealtime", false))
        )
                .filter(l ->
                        l.getT3() ||
                        (!l.getT2().getEndTimeStr().equals(l.getT1().getEndTimeStr())))
                .map(Tuple2::getT1)
                .log()
                .map(this::
}
```

which is input to this this:

```
    public void setRealtime(Flux<Bar> input) {
        Flux.zip(input, Mono.subscriberContext())
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
...
   })
                .doOnNext(t -> {
...
    })
    .subscribe()
}
```

I can tell my code in `...` is not failing, I can even access the `Context` map, but when the first iteration completes, I get:

```
onContextUpdate(Context1{reactor.onNextError.localStrategy=reactor.core.publisher.OnNextFailureStrategy$ResumeStrategy@35d5ac51})
```

and subscriber disconnects.

So my question is whether I am using it right and what can be an issue here?

**EDIT:**

I have tried to `repeat()` the `Mono.subscriberContext()` when I'm using value out of it:

```
        return Flux.zip(
                ohlcIntfFlux,
                ohlcIntfFlux.skip(1),
                Mono.subscriberContext()
                        .map(c -> c.getOrDefault("isRealtime", new AtomicBoolean())).repeat()
        )
                .filter(l ->
                        l.getT3().get() ||
                                (!l.getT2().getEndTime().isEqual(l.getT1().getEndTime())))
                .map(Tuple2::getT1)
```

and set the `AtomicBoolean` to the context on the subscriber end and just change the value inside this variable reference, when I need the signal on the upstream, but it doesn't change at all:

```
        input
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> throwable.getMessage())
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Number of trades for the strategy: " + tradingRecord.getTradeCount());
                    // Analysis
                    System.out.println("Total profit for the strategy: " + new TotalProfitCriterion().calculate(timeSeries, tradingRecord));
                })
                .doOnNext(this::defaultRealtimeEvaluator)
                .subscriberContext(Context.of("isRealtime", isRealtimeAtomic))
                .subscribe();
```

at least with repeat the `Flux` doesn't disconnect but the value I'm getting out of it is not being updated. No other clues I have.

Spring-webflux: 2.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
        input
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> throwable.getMessage())
                .doOnComplete(() -> { ... }
                .flatMap(bar -> Mono.subscriberContext()
                        .map(c -> Tuples.of(bar, c)))
                .doOnNext(this::defaultRealtimeEvaluator)
                .subscriberContext(Context.of("isRealtime", new AtomicBoolean()))
                .subscribe();
```

so the point is to set `AtomicBoolean` in my case as the cotnext and then extract this variable out of the context if you want to change it's value. the same on the upstream flux.